# python aiohttp and asyncio without loop event

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My understanding that the "async def " needs to be called with loop_event, e.g.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(<method>)
```

I created some code below without the loop. It still supports 100 async calls without an issue. Did I miss anything?

Dummy server sleeps 5 seconds.

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio
import time

async def hello(request):
    #time.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return web.Response(text='dummy done')

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])

web.run_app(app,host='127.0.0.1', port=8081)
```

Actual server taking requests.

```
import json
from aiohttp import web
import aiohttp
import asyncio

n = 0

def mcowA(n):
   print (n, " : A") 
   return

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with getattr(session,"get")(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

def mcowB(n):
   print (n, " : B") 
   return

async def runMcows(request):
    global n
    n = n + 1
    mcowA(n)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://localhost:8081')
    print(n,html)
    mcowB(n)
    return web.Response(text=html)

try:
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', runMcows)])
    #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(web.run_app(app))
    #loop.run_forever()
    web.run_app(app)
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: When you call `web.run_app`, it finds an event loop for you, and runs the server on that event loop. This is why you don't need to call `run_until_complete` - `run_app` [does it for you](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/c562ffe32182aaeca7c03d5b97b90fc4f84985f5/aiohttp/web.py#L375).

Comment: If I change the http://localhost:8081 to http://www.google.com, every request is timed out? Isn't the run_app doing the same thing?